# AIDL access through filter application list

Tags: android, aidl

The AIDL service is able to access for accessing different information and as AIDL service can be able to access through other application. So, in the mean time I am very much feel the security issue of accessing that AIDL service by other components. How could AIDL service can be forbid the accessing from other application. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Statically, you can protect your service in `AndroidManifest.xml` using permissions. You can find tons of information how to do this in the Internet.

Moreover, there is also a not obvious case of dynamic enforcement of permissions. During the implementation of your service you can check dynamically if a calling application is assigned with a special permission using methods `Context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission`, `Context.checkCallingPermission`, `Context.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission` and `Context.enforceCallingPermission`.